# how to mock @click="openModal($index)" in vue test utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-test-utils

How do I mock this call in vue test utils:
@click="openModal($index)"

doing

```
pricingForm.find('.enable-tiers-icon').trigger('click', { $index: 0 });
```

doesn't work, tried a couple other things as well

Comment: Are you sure that the element `.enable-tiers-icon` has the click handler bound to it and exists within the DOM at the time of the attempted trigger?

Answer (score 1):

it's vm.$emit('click', { $index: 0 });